# Why does the subshell assignment stay empty although command inside prints result

Tags: bash, shell, go, github

I'm doing some scripting using the github cli tool [gh](https://github.com/cli/cli), where I create a pull-request and close it. It's all straight forward, but I can't figure out why the assignment of the subshell result of `gh pr merge` command stays empty.

```
response="$(gh pr merge $url --merge)"
```

When the command is run by itself it will show a spinner which disappears then print the result

```
⠏    # <- spinner
✓ Closed pull request #21 (test)
```

Also piping to `grep` will print nothing

```
gh pr merge $url --merge | grep 'Closed'
```

I've already tried without success

- redirecting stderr to stdout via `2>&1`
- redirecting both stderr and stdout to a file via `&> out.txt`

I haven't seen anything suspicious going on at the source [pr/merge/merge.go](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/09a92c6e1dda467208a51455e23ce16f401be247/pkg/cmd/pr/merge/merge.go#L154)

There seems to be something process-related going on inside.

Under what circumstances does a bash subshell result stay empty although the command inside the subshell prints an output ?

Comment: Have you tried redirecting the command to a file and retrieving the output of the file? Something similar to `gh pr merge $url --merge 2>&1 > output.txt ; response=$(cat output.txt)`

Comment: Just tried that. File is empty.

Comment: Then `gh` doesn't print anything if stdout/stderr is not a terminal. Use an alternative tool that isn't for interactive-use only.

Comment: @oguzismail when run by itself `gh` prints on the terminal. The code also checks if it's run inside a terminal [/cmd/pr/merge/merge.go#L264](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/09a92c6e1dda467208a51455e23ce16f401be247/pkg/cmd/pr/merge/merge.go#L264) Could have something to do with streaming perhaps.

Comment: try this `gh pr status &> test.txt`

Comment: it did capture the content here.

Comment: @mh-cbon that works for `pr status`, but not for `pr merge`

Comment: @dnltinney This is deep eldritch magic that I do not understand, but try `cat <(gh pr merge) &> test.txt`